# Reactnative: Query and Filter Firestore Database and save a single returned document field value in a const/var

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have setup a Firebase Firestore Database and would like to filter it for a certain field value in a document.
I have a collection called "PRD" with thousands of documents where all contain the same fields. One of these fields a Document contains is a GTIN Number (String). I am receiving this Number from a Bar Code (called data), and would like to retrieve the Medication Name (called DSCRD, a different Field in all these Documents) using the GTIN Number scanned.

I am having difficulties with retrieving the Value from the Firebase and the documentation doesn't seem to get me any further. I have tried various retrieval methods. At the moment the code for retrieval looks like this:

```
import { dbh } from "../firebase/config"
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore'
```

```
    dbh.collection('PRD')
    .where('GTIN', '==', data)
    .get()
    .then(documentSnapshot => {

      console.log('MedData',documentSnapshot.data())    
    });
```

I am unsure how to filter the right medicament using the GTIN provided by the Barcode scanner and then save the specific field value for the description of this medicament to a variable.

Firebase is setup correctly since I am able to write whole collections and documents in it.

Here is the database structure, as you can see there is the PRD Collection with all the medicaments and every medicament containing the GTIN and DSCRD Fields:

[image]

Comment: 1) What is the value of `data`? 2) If you hard-code the GTIN value in `.where('GTIN', '==', data)`, can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: The value of the data is a GTIN number that can be found to identify the single medicaments. Every medicament has one, sort of an unique identifier.

I haven't tried that yet since I was thinking it would't have anything to do with it because the number that is retourned in data is 1to1 the same as the GTIN's saved on the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that you are trying to call `documentSnapshot.data()` after querying a collection. This is the syntax you would use if you were fetching a single document. Your current query will return a list of documents which you need to handle like this:

```
.then(querySnapshot => {
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log('MedData', doc.data())  
  })  
});
```

Assuming that the GTIN will fetch one unique document (will it?) then you can just use the only document returned by the query to get the name of the Medication like this:

```
    var medName
    dbh.collection('PRD')
    .where('GTIN', '==', data)
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
       querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          console.log('MedData', doc.data())  
          medName = doc.data().DSCRD
       })  
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I will test this out immediatly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I am trying to recieve a single document (filtered by the where using the GTIN number). When the document is found in the DB I would like to use a different field (description) from the retrieved document and save it in a obejct or variable or whatever):

Comment: When I scan the code for one medi I get 7680407700388 as text back, which matches the GTIN in the firebase seen on the screenshot.

Comment: when I give out the medname in log (which should contain only de doc.data().DSCRD) I still get the whole object back instead of only the the DSCRD. Why is that?

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like it worked now. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Awesome I am glad it worked. Since you are using a where query you will get a list back even if only one document matched the query. doc.data().DSCRD will return that specific med name though. Also note that medName will be null if no document matched that GTIN